# Pass some data from cordova plugin to activity in android

Tags: android, cordova

I have activity and plugin from cordova. In Activity I have cordovawebview. Now I get some data in plugin and want to send this data to activity without startActivity. I have a problem **because I don't know when I get data in plugin** so I am searching for way to when I get data in plugin I send this data to activity without recreating. 
This is my plugin:

```
public class ChartPhoneGap extends CordovaPlugin{           
    String dateFrom, dateTo, dataFromText, dataToText;          

    @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
            /*if(action.equals("echo")){
                String message = args.getString(0); 
                callbackContext.success(message);
                return true;
            }*/
            dateFrom = args.getString(0);
            dataFromText = format.format(Long.parseLong(dateFrom));
            dateTo = args.getString(1);
            dataToText = format.format(Long.parseLong(dateTo));

            callbackContext.success(action);
            return true;
        }


     public String getDateFrom() {
        return dataFromText;
        }
    public void setDateFrom(String dateFrom) {
        this.dataFromText = dateFrom;
        }
    public String getDateTo() {
        return dataToText;
        }
    public void setDateTo(String dateTo) {
        this.dataToText = dateTo;
        }

    }
```